# How to Install latest version of Node js for Elementary OS (ubuntu)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, elementary-os, node.js

I have downloaded node v5 for Linux on the *[node website](https://nodejs.org/en/) and found some instructions on how to Install a `tar.gz` file but this file ends with `tar.xz` and I can't find any instructions for that. Please help. I have also tried `sudo apt-get install` which installs a very old version of Node.

Comment: `.gz` and `.xz` are just different compression. The instructions to install will be the same once you have untarred the package. If you want, you can get the corresponding `.gz` file from https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.2/

Comment: Check this. http://phpsmashcode.com/tutorial/how-to-install-node-js-in-elementary-os-using-terminal

Answer (score 1):

Try to install from Terminal

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[Check this](http://phpsmashcode.com/tutorial/how-to-install-node-js-in-elementary-os-using-terminal) for more details.

Comment: You should never pipe into bash. You should first check out the code you downloaded and only then execute it.